# Concatenation In C

Tags: c, string, concatenation

Im creating an array of structs and i need to concatenate a string value with the for loop index.

this is how i create the struct:

```
typedef struct b
{
char title[30];
char author[40];
int year,price;

}
book_t;
```

then I create an array using malloc:

```
int m;
printf ("array size:\n");
scanf("%d",&m);
B= (book_t *) malloc (m*sizeof ( book_t));
```

and then i need to pass values to fill the array in this form:
Title_i,
Author_i,
1000+i,
3 * i for i=1...m
so im using this for loop:

```
for(i=1;i<=m;i++){
    B[i-1].title='title_';
    B[i-1].author='author_';
    B[i-1].year=1000_i;
    B[i-1].price=3*i;
    }
```

any ideas on how can i get the i value of every loop next to the string value for the title and the author field?

Comment: How about itoa function?
void* itoa(int input, char *buffer, int radix)

Comment: `sprintf(B[i-1].title, "title_%d", i);`

Comment: @Anton: That's neither C nor POSIX. BTW: [Don't cast the result of malloc (and friends)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845), character literals `'A'` are not string literals `"string"`.

Comment: @ Anton: if im running the first loop, i need the author field to be author_1, the second time author_2 etc. i dont want to convert  int to ASCII.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this loop

```
for(i=1;i<=m;i++){
    B[i-1].title='title_';
    B[i-1].author='author_';
    B[i-1].year=1000_i;
    B[i-1].price=3*i;
    }
```

to

```
for ( i = 0; i < m; i++ )
{
    sprintf( B[i].title, "%s%d", "title_", i + 1 );
    sprintf( B[i].author, "%s%d", "author_", i + 1 );
    B[i].year = 1000 + i + 1;
    B[i].price = 3 * ( i + 1 );
}
```

I think that instead of `1000_i` you mean `1000 + i + 1`

Comment: why supply `"title_"` as an arg to `sprintf` when it could have been in the format string?

Comment: @Alnitak I prefer the record I am using because instead of "title_" there can be any variable. That is it is a more general approach.